# How to run an SQL server with a dockerfile

Tags: mysql, database, docker, dockerfile

Im trying to create an sql server in docker which will dump my current SQL database.
Every tutorial I have seen is of people using the command line which is something I don't want to do as I will likely be doing this fairly often.

Does anyone have a decent format for this?

My current looks like this:

```
FROM mysql
ENV MYSQL_USER=admin
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD=admin
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=yesdb
ENV MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
RUN mysql CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'
```

Comment: How do you define _decent format_ ?

Comment: Anything that doesnt cause an error

Comment: How do you run your image? Do you use port mapping?

Comment: I didnt get to that stage because this error occurs during built